# Using Memcached to cache results from Model::find()

Tags: memcached, lithium

I'd like to store the DocumentSet returned from Model::find() in memcached. However, I get the MongoException below when I try to work with the results after retrieving them from cache. Specifically, when using foreach, the exception is thrown when calling `if ($this->_resource->hasNext())` on line 63 of \data\source\mongo_db\Result.php

**MongoException**

> The MongoCursor object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor

I can understand why this would be the case.

My question is, is there anyway to pre-populate a Model::find() or create my own DocumentSet so that I can work with the data? Normally, I'd just convert it to an array and store that in cache. However, I need access to some of the Model methods I've written (ex: Customer::fullName())

***Update***: I've found a bit of a workound that is *ok* but not great. I'm saving the Model::find() results as an array in cache `$result->to('array')`. Then, upon retrieval, I loop through the $results and populate a new array with `Model::create($result, array("exists" => true)` for each $result;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DocumentSet` returned by `Model::find` contains a Mongo db cursor.  It doesn't load all of the data from the database until the items are iterated.  As each item is iterated, a `Document` is created and is cached in memory into the DocumentSet object.  The built-in php function `iterator_to_array()` can be used to turn the DocumentSet into an array of documents which you could cache.

As you mention in your update, you can also use `->to('array')` to prepare for caching and then `Model::create()` to build it back up.  One caveat with that method: when you use `->to('array')` it also casts MongoId and MongoDate objects to strings and integers respectively.  If you've defined a `$_schema` for your model and set the `'id'` and `'date'` types, they will be cast back to the original MongoId and MongoDate objects in the Document returned by `Model::create()`.  If you don't have a schema for all of your fields, it can be a problem.  I have a [recent pull request](https://github.com/rmarscher/lithium/commit/ded7bb37c2e7978dddea474468287a96a94caa56) that tries to make it possible to do `->to('array')` without casting the native mongo objects (also fixes a problem with the mongo objects always being casted when inside arrays of sub-documents).

FWIW, I actually prefer saving just the data in cache because it's less space than serializing a whole php object and avoids potential issues with classes not being defined or other items not initialized when the item is pulled from cache.

I haven't tried this... but I would think you could make a cache strategy class that would take care of this transparently for you.  Another example of the great care that went into making Lithium a very flexible and powerful framework.  http://li3.me/docs/lithium/storage/cache/strategy

Comment: I like your custom strategy idea. For the time being, I'm relying on $_schema for correct type casting.